# Visual Basic, Read database(Ms Access) directly from it's project map instead from C:drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, database-connection, connection-string

I want to put the database with the projects file, meaning

```
location = "\Database.mdb'.
```

However I'm getting error

> "Could not find file 'C:\Database.mdb'..

How do I make the project look into it's own path instead from C: drive?

This is how far i got:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\Database.mdb"
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString1" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdb"
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Remove the leading forward slash from the path, as that redirects to the root.

Comment: @stuartd Got error: `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Database.mdb'.` . By having `connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb"`

Comment: Looks like the current directory is IIS Express. Using [DataDirectory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce) is probably the way to go.

Comment: @stuartd Got error when I called connection-string in code: `Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 33.`. I've no idea what that means.

Comment: That's telling you that the connection string is invalid. You need to set `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "[your directory]")` __before__ accessing the connection string.

Comment: @stuartd Oh silly me I simply missed a "=" in `Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database.mdb"`. So it works now, thanks. However I had to put mdb file in App_Data folder, otherwise it couldn't read it.